"in a little bit" VS "a little while later." (in the context of time)
A man wants to read a book, because he is curious about it and needs a quiet home, so he tells everyone in the house:

I'm gonna read it, so everybody go to bed. I will go to bed in a little bit.

I didn't know that "in a little bit" can refer to time. I would think it is used for physical things. Anyway, as a non native speaker, I would probably say:

I will go to bed "a little while later".

When I think about them, they both seem to mean the same in meaning to me. Do they really, to native english speakers, too?

Yes they mean the same thing.  "in a little bit" is used for non-physical things quite commonly, such as time, courage, love, etc.

In a little while would be more idiomatic. The next day he could say "I sent everyone to bed, and I went up an hour later".

This is easily answered with a dictionary, so I have voted to close it.

Younger children often say "I'll do it in a bit", but (precisely because it might be seen as "childish") lots of adults drop the usage. It's not important. Think of it as reduced from a bit of time if you need help getting used to it.

'In a bit' is informal; 'in a while' is not.

We would use "a little while later" retrospectively rather than postpone something in the present. You'll see it in the narrative of books to describe the gap between two past events. For example, "I saw him go into the shop, and then emerge a little while later carrying a box".
'Later' means at a time in the future or after the time you have mentioned. When you're talking about two past events it makes sense to describe the second one as "later", or after the other. It doesn't make sense to say "in a while later" because in a while it will be later. What you mean, when someone asks you if you're doing something now is "later than now". So you'd say either "in a while" or "later".

You can also use it for two future events. "I'll do X at 10am, then do Y a little while later." It's still the case that "later" needs some previous event to be relative to.

"I'll do X at 10am, then do Y a bit later"  is perfectly idiomatic even for many adult native speakers who wouldn't say "I'll be ready in a bit" (which is a bit "childish / uneducated").

@FumbleFingers That's two future events.

I don't see how "two future events" affects anything. My point was that at least some people are more accepting of a bit explicitly modifying later, even though they might have misgivings about using bare ...in a bit modifying an unstated / implicit later (...when a bit more time has elapsed).
